# Step by Step guide to setup Ubuntu VPS server with at least lamp, email and ftp

Tags: vps, installation, ubuntu-12.04

Sorry If it is duplicate, but I can't find nice way for this.

Can anyone please suggest me on how to setup an UBUNTU 12.04 - 64bit VPS to host website. The server should have lamp, email and FTP at least.

I'm new to VPS so please suggest me a step by step guide for installation and configuration. And how can I check if everything is working perfectly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Short guide: http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-apache2-with-php5-and-mysql-support-on-ubuntu-12.10-lamp

Full guide(it's much complex your needs, but you can skip some steps): http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-10.04-lucid-lynx-ispconfig-3

I hope it helps.

Comment: Link-only answers are strongly discouraged. Please provide content **here** and then link elsewhere for more details.

Comment: Print full guide to setup ubuntu for novice from scratch looks not a good idea. Sincerely you, Paul Rudnitskiy.

Comment: That is why we don't generally answer such questions at all.